# Can't run passenger-install-apache2-module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger

now I want to install passenger into my CentOS6.4.

I installed passenger by {gem install passenger}.but I can't run {passenger-install-apache2-module}.because the following error has occured !

please tell me how to fix the problem !

```
/home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:188:in ``': No such file or directory - /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs -q CFLAGS (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:188:in `apache2_module_cflags'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:110:in `apache2_module_cflags'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:293:in `apr_config_needed_for_building_apache_modules?'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:92:in `apr_config_needed_for_building_apache_modules?'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:69:in `dependencies'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_installer.rb:166:in `check_dependencies'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:90:in `install!'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_installer.rb:63:in `start'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/passenger-3.0.19/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:236:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:19:in `load'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/kenta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the apache development headers/tools

Comment: Deer Fredrick.Thank you for replying ! you are right ! I forgot to install some headers/tools. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I installed some headers&tools,and solved this problem.

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel e2fsprogs-devel krb5-devel libidn-devel curl-devel
```